# I want to set ng model's value with value attribute's value

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

```
<input type="text" value="{{id}}" class="form-control" id="pid" ng-model="user.id" readonly />
```

if text box's value is 1 i want to set the user.id value as 1

Comment: Change your ng-model to id

Comment: Why you want to do it? If id is scope variable then in controller you can init it by $scope.user.id = $scope.id And after that with Angular's two way data binding model will be updated as soon as you make change in textbox

Answer (score 2):

You can add dynamic attribute binding, using angular's directive.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-attr-value="{{title}}" class="form-control" id="pid" ng-model="title" readonly />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.title = "I 'm a tooltip!";    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QzHe3/209/)

Answer (score 1):

Try Following code,

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("InputController", function($scope) {
    $scope.user={"id":1};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="InputController">
      <input type="text" value="{{user.id}}" class="form-control" id="pid" ng-model="user.id" readonly />
    </body>
```